# Nop.Plugin.Payments.Paytm.PaytmPaymentProcessor' does not implement interface member 'Nop.Services.Payments.IPaymentMethod.PaymentMethodDescription'

Tags: nopcommerce, paytm, nopcommerce-3.80

I am unable to integrate paytm payment module in nopcommerce. I am getting an error which is given below.

> Error  6   'Nop.Plugin.Payments.Paytm.PaytmPaymentProcessor' does not implement interface member 'Nop.Services.Payments.IPaymentMethod.PaymentMethodDescription'   E:\Test\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Paytm\PaytmPaymentProcessor.cs  25  18  Nop.Plugin.Payments.Paytm

Comment: Hi, Have you successfully integrated Paytm plugin on NOP 3.90?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PaymentMethodDescription` it is a new property of `IPaymentMethod`, which will appear only in version nopCommerce 3.90. And since this version has not yet been released it is naturally that none of the plugin supports it.

You can wait for the release of new version and updating this plugin, or use the version for which it was created.

Comment: Hi, Have you successfully integrated Paytm on NOP 3.90?

Comment: @HITESHKUMARVAGHASIYA, I will check today.

Comment: @MusakkhirSayyed ... Ok Thanks. Let me know if it is done.